# Как сделать авто растяжку background ImageView?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

У меня имеется определенные тексты(описания курса). Тексты разной длины. Помогите узнать пожалуйста как я могу сделать так чтобы фон тянулся относительно текста а также передвигал элементы снизу (ImageView и Button в LinearLayout). Я пробовал использовать android:scaleType="fitXY", однако оно ничего не изменило (либо я неправильно его применил)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/connect_bkgrnd"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/courseTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Course Title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/courseDescriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Course Description"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startDateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Продолжительность курса: "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startDateMonth"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="время"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/costCourse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Cтоимость"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactButton"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:text="@string/connect"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Запуск: "
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/startDateValue"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startDateValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Дата"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что применяли `android:scaleType="fitXY"` к самому первому ImageView, у которого стоит `backgroud`, то вы правильно всё пытались делать, просто надо использовать атрибут `src` вместо `background` - тогда `scaleType` будет работать.